# How to set Job-specific minPayment in v2 jobs for job type webhook?

Tags: chainlink

Chainlink v1 jobs allowed to set job-specific mininmum Payment with the `minPayment` keyword

```json
{
  "initiators": [
    {
      "type": "RunLog",
      "params": { "address": "0x51DE85B0cD5B3684865ECfEedfBAF12777cd0Ff8" }
    }
  ],
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "HTTPGet",
      "confirmations": 0,
      "params": { "get": "https://bitstamp.net/api/ticker/" }
    },
    {
      "type": "JSONParse",
      "params": { "path": [ "last" ] }
    },
    {
      "type": "Multiply",
      "params": { "times": 100 }
    },
    { "type": "EthUint256" },
    { "type": "EthTx" }
  ],
  "startAt": "2020-02-09T15:13:03Z",
  "endAt": null,
  "minPayment": "1000000000000000000"
}
```

It seems to be missing in v2 toml jobs. For now only directRequest type v2 jobs have this which were added with this [PR](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/pull/4905)

The v1 Job type that serves our purpose is.

```
  name: 'get-request',
  initiators: [
    {
      type: 'external',
      params: {
        name: process.env.CHAINLINK_EI_NAME,
        body: {},
      },
    },
  ],
  tasks: [
    {
      type: 'httpget',
    },
    {
      type: 'jsonparse',
    },
    {
      type: process.env.CHAINLINK_BRIDGE_NAME,
    },
  ],
  minPayment: '1',
};
```

How can we set minPayment for webhook type jobs in v2 TOML jobs?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the `minContractPaymentLinkJuels`.

For example:

```
type                                 = "directrequest"
schemaVersion                        = 1
name                                 = "my job"
contractAddress                      = "ORACLE_ADDRESS_HERE"
minContractPaymentLinkJuels          = 1000000000000000000
observationSource = """
    ds1          [type=bridge name="bridge-data-feed" requestData="{\\"data\\": {\\"from\\":\\"eth\\", \\"to\\", \\"USD\\"}}"];

    ds1
```

For `webhook` type jobs, you'll [actually want to use a custom `spec`](https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/types/webhook/) (for example with an external initiator)

```
type            = "webhook"
schemaVersion   = 1
externalInitiators = [
  { name = "my-external-initiator-1", spec = "{\"minContractPaymentLinkJuels\": 1000000000000000000}" },
]
observationSource   = """
    ds1          [type=bridge name="bridge-data-feed" requestData="{\\"data\\": {\\"from\\":\\"eth\\", \\"to\\", \\"USD\\"}}"];

    ds1
"""
```

The `spec` defines the JSON payload that will be sent to the External Initiator on job creation if the external initiator has a URL, and you can check the amount sent to the node is correct.

Comment: This is for job type "directrequest"  this does not work for job type "webhook"
Is there something similar for job type "webhook"?

Comment: "webhook" jobs don't take payment. RunLog has been replaced by directrequest. webhook is equivalent to web jobs

Comment: webhook jobs can be triggered by an external initiator (EI) we have a case where EI triggers a job upon receiving an event from another chain (stacks blockchain) now this job needs to have a minimum payment which we need to verify is transferred before running the job (This validation and job run is done using an external adapter) but the job spec must have a minimum payment property which can be fetched and verified by External Adapter.

Comment: I have added the v1 Job we are using that serves the purpose gracefully.

Comment: Updated, does that answer it?

Comment: It does create the job with this EI custom spec but when i get jobspec using get job endpoint /v2/jobs/{jobid} The custom spec added is not present returned in response. Neither it is returned in EI get endpoint /v2/external_initiators.

Comment: Hmm... thanks for your detailed answers. Could you please make an issue here: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/issues